# Dumping Database to Heroku app

Tags: postgresql, heroku, pg-dump

I've been trying to dump a database file to my heroku app.

I generated a PG dump file by calling

```
pg_dump mydb > db.sql
```

Then I uploaded that to an amazons3 and uploaded it to heroku via:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\gvf-api>heroku pgbackups:restore 
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GREEN_URL 's3.amazonaws.com/mydb'
```

The fictional url really works so that's not the issue

I get a `Retrieving... done` and a `Restoring... done` message when I run the call.

Problem is no data in the tables.

also I've used the dump file to re-create the database on my local machine successfully.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following modifiers to the dump command as suggested [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import),

```
pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump
```

After a few minutes the data did show up.

Comment: I did exactly the same, and heroku logs says it's ok but database is still empty

Comment: it might take a while. make sure the host and user are correct.